# not able to send file from form to view

Tags: ajax, django, django-uploads

When i try to send data from form to view, All data is sent successfully except FileField Data.i am using CURD datatable screenshot of the template is also pasted below. 
I am also use ajax.
I am beginner in Django please help i am not able to find error.

> screenshot

[image: sjx]

> view.py

```
def list(request):
    certificatedata = certificateDb.objects.all()
    context = {
    'certificatedata': certificatedata
    }
    return render(request, 'list.html',context)

def save_all(request,form,template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True

            certificatedata = certificateDb.objects.all()
            data['list'] = render_to_string('list_2.html',{'certificatedata':certificatedata})
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {
    'form':form
    }
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name,context,request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)

def certificate_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CertificateForm(request.POST, request.FILES )
        print('request.FILES',request.FILES)
    else:
        form = CertificateForm()
    return save_all(request,form,'certificate_create.html')
```

> form.py

```
from django import forms
from SharedApps_Application.models import serviceDb
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget
from django.forms.fields import DateField

class CertificateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    startdate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1995, 2100)))
    expiredate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1995, 2100)))
    class Meta:
        model = certificateDb
        fields = ('application', 'startdate', 'expiredate', 'environment_type','file' )
```

> urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns=[
url(r'^list/$', views.list, name='list'),
    url(r'^list/create$', views.certificate_create, name='certificate_create'),
    url(r'^list/(?P<id>\d+)/update$', views.certificate_update, name='certificate_update'),
    url(r'^list/(?P<id>\d+)/delete$', views.certificate_delete, name='certificate_delete'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> Create_certifcate.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-url="{% url 'certificate_create' %}" class="create-form" >
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" >Create certificate</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        {{form|crispy}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Certificate</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

> certificate.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ShowForm = function(){
        var btn = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: btn.attr("data-url"),
            type: 'get',
            dataType:'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#modal-certificate').modal('show');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#modal-certificate .modal-content').html(data.html_form);
            }
        });
    };
    var SaveForm =  function(){
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('data-url'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.form_is_valid){
                    $('#Certificate-table tbody').html(data.list);
                    $('#modal-certificate').modal('hide');
                    jQuery("body").load(window.location.href);
                } else {
                    $('#modal-certificate .modal-content').html(data.html_form)
                    jQuery("body").load(window.location.href);
                }
            }
        })
        return false;
    }
// create 
$(".show-form").click(ShowForm);
$("#modal-certificate").on("submit",".create-form",SaveForm);

//update
$('#Certificate-table').on("click",".show-form-update",ShowForm);
$('#modal-certificate').on("submit",".update-form",SaveForm)

//delete
$('#Certificate-table').on("click",".show-form-delete",ShowForm);
$("#modal-certificate").on("submit",".delete-form",SaveForm);

});
```

Comment: set `contentType` to `multipart/form-data` in ajax.

Comment: where in ajax. in datatype

Comment: In saveform ajax config `contentType: 'multipart/form-data',`

Comment: var SaveForm =  function(){
  var form = $(this);
  $.ajax({
   url: form.attr('data-url'),
   data: form.serialize(),
   type: form.attr('method'),
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: 'multipart/form-data'
   success: function(data){
    if(data.form_is_valid){
     $('#Certificate-table tbody').html(data.list);
     $('#modal-certificate').modal('hide');
     jQuery("body").load(window.location.href);
    } else {
     $('#modal-certificate .modal-content').html(data.html_form)
     jQuery("body").load(window.location.href);
    }
   }
  })
  return false;

Comment: tried but not working pls.help

Comment: instead of `var form = $(this);` use `var formdata = new FormData($(this)[0])` and in `saveForm = $.ajax({url: 'your url',type: 'POST', data: formdata, contentType: false, processData: false})`

Comment: 'var SaveForm =  function(){
  var formdata = new FormData($(this)[0])
  $.ajax({
   url: form.attr('data-url'),
   data: formdata,
   contentType: false
   processData: false
   type: 'POST',      
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
    if(data.form_is_valid){
     $('#Certificate-table tbody').html(data.list);
     $('#modal-certificate').modal('hide');
     jQuery("body").load(window.location.href);
    } else {
     $('#modal-certificate .modal-content').html(data.html_form)
     jQuery("body").load(window.location.href);
    
   }}
  })
  
 }'

Comment: still not working